# Android Bluetooth connection polar - keep sending data after removing chest belt

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth, bytebuffer

Hard to find the right title...

My android application connects to a polar bluetooth chest belt. It receives the bytes and parses the heart rate, rr-interval and so on. When the test person removes the chest belt (sensor), the service still receives data, which are nonsense. Either the rr-intervals are 2295ms or 0ms...

First I thought the connection between the service and the polar sensor is kept open, because the service constantly reads the buffer of the bluetooth socket. But as soon as I "reattache" the sensor to the test person I get an error saying bluetooth connection is lost.

IMO this is a strange behaviour: I would assume that either:

- the connection is lost as soon as the test person removes the sensor (maybe a few seconds later)

or

- that the connection is kept open, as long as the service reads data. If the test person is not wearing the sensor the service receives "nonsense" data but as soon as he put the sensor back on the sensor gets the measured values (since the connection is open over the whole time).

My question: How can I trigger one of these options?